# Нужно обрезать текст на JS (по символам+ближайший пробел)

Tags: javascript

Нужно обрезать по 40 символов + ближайшему пробелу...

например:

> Текст лучший самый на свете - обрезка(Текст лучший самый)

Получилось только так

```
const productTitle = $('.li');
const limit = 40;

productTitle.each((e, i) => {
  if (i.text.length > 40) {
    i.text = `${i.text.slice(0, limit)}...`;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод `String.replace()` с заменой по регулярному выражению

```
(^.{N}([^ ]+|\s))(.*)
```

и с выбрасыванием второй группы

- `^.{N}` - берем N любых (`.`) символов от начала строки (`^`). Где N **на единицу меньше** от необходимого количества
- `([^ ]+|\s)` - затем должен идти один или более непробельных символов или пробел
- `(.*)` - а потом может идти все, что угодно

```js
const productTitle = 'Текст лучший самый на свете';
const limit = 10;
const re = new RegExp("(^.{" + (limit - 1) + "}([^ ]+|\\s))(.*)");
const cut = productTitle.replace(re, '$1');
console.log(cut);
```

Или без константы `limit`

```js
const productTitle = 'Текст лучший самый на свете';
const cut = productTitle.replace(/(^.{9}([^ ]+|\s))(.*)/, '$1');
console.log(cut);
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо 10 числа 5 и 6

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Спасибо за уточнение. Поправил регексп

Comment: Все еще выводит в первом если поставить 5 то одно слово, если 6 - всю строку. Во втором если 5 то одно слово, 6 - 2 слова.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько В первом забыл проекранировать `\`. Если подставляете 6, то это означает, что нужно обрезать 7 и более. Так, что два слова законные. Я в пояснении написал, что число `N - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = 'Текст лучший самый на свете   после пробела'
//          обрезает до сюда(включительно) ^

console.log(get(text))

function get (text, limit = 30) {
  const slice = text.slice(0, limit)
  // лучший в мире способ определить пробелы
  const rightWhitespace = /[\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\u2028\u2029\uFEFF]*$/
  
  return slice.replace(rightWhitespace, '') + '...'
}
```